# How to copy one Photo to two folders in one copy operation?

Tags: macos, automation, productivity

I would like to achieve the following:

When I copy one photo into Folder `A`, I want to the same photo to be copied to folder `B`.

So what I want to do basically is to copy a photo to two folders with one copy command.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Ok, any ideas why the vote to close? It is not a question about opinions. It is about how to do something and whether it is possible in the first place.

Comment: You could use the Terminal `cp` command to copy to multiple locations: